# GitHub web hosting "This binary file is changed."

Tags: github, web

I'm trying to use GitHub to host my website. First I create an repository online, next I downloaded the GitHub (desktop version), I cloned the existent repository and move my web page to the folder that I want. Next I just commit, uploaded the files and open the link https://joaocadavez.github.io/ (If you want to see what's going on). Some photos aren't loading on the web, and that same photos are getting this code on the GitHub "This binary file is changed." [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk8B2.png). There is any thing that I can make about that??
PS: I already turn the size of the photos smaller.